# Node doesn't appear to update using 'n'

Tags: node.js, macos, path, n

I just noticed I'm on node version 4.0.0 and want to update to the latest version so I installed 'n' and ran `sudo n stable` in terminal

> ```
> Machine-Name:directory name User$ sudo n stable
> ```
>
> install : node-v9.8.0
>      mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/node/9.8.0
>      fetch : https://nodejs.org/dist/v9.8.0/node-v9.8.0-darwin-x64.tar.gz
>
> ################################################################## 100.0%    installed : v4.0.0
>
> ```
> Machine-Name:directory name User$ node -v
> ```
>
> v4.0.0

The latest version downloads, but the installed version remains at v4.0.0. Is there something else I need to do in order for node to install/use the downloaded version?

Answer (score 1):

The issue will be that you have two versions of `node` now. `n` installs to `/usr/local/` by default and presumably you have another version of `node` earlier in your `PATH`.

If you are happy with the `n` managed version then a simple approach is to uninstall the other one.

Alternatively, you could modify `PATH` to prioritize `/usr/local/` over the other location. [from comments]

(If your OS supports it, `which -a node` shows the locations of all the versions in your `PATH`.)

Comment: Could also modify `PATH` to re-prioritize `/usr/local/` over the other location

Comment: I ended up going with @PatrickRoberts solution back in March and forgot to post a solution. Patrick if you want to post that as a solution, I'll accept it

Comment: Good comment. Likewise, can define N_PREFIX to install to a custom location and (again) edit PATH.